# Overwintering Lavender Meerlo

Tags: overwintering, lavender

I have a lavender meerlo

[image]

[Picture source](https://gpnmag.com/ccv/lavender-meerlo-2/)

I live in Austria, I think zone 7A (-17.8°C - -15°C). My apartment is on the 4th floor, facing north. I'm reluctant to leave the plant on the balcony during the winter. My options are:

- inside the apartment or my office, c.a. constant 20-22°C, not too much light, since windows face north
- down to the cellar, which I think is worse, because there is no light, and the temperature is higher, c.a. 22-24°C

I guess [laying the plant dormant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/how-do-you-overwinter-a-container-plant) is not an option because of the relatively high temperature. So how should I care for it?

Comment: You'll have to bring it indoors, but it will do better away from heat sources and with as much sunlight as possible...

Comment: Give it to a friend to care for?